# Suppose U and V are independent and follow the geometric distribution...

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose $U$ and $V$ are independent and follow the geometric
>   distribution.
>
> $p(k)=p(1-p)^k \ $ for $ \ k=0,1,...$
>
> Define the random variable $Z = U + V$.
>
> (a) Determine the joint probability mass function $P_{ \ U,Z}(u, z) 
> = Pr(U=u, \ Z=z)$.
>
> (b) Determine the conditional probability mass function for $U$ given
>   that $Z = n$.

For (a) I got $p^2(1-p)^z \ $ for $ \ 0 \le u \le z$. (This is correct, for sure)

Now I'm stuck on part (b).

Tthe correct answer is $\frac{1}{n+1} \ $ for $ \ 0 \le u \le n$ but I don't know how to get to that.

Comment: for (b), you might use $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.

Comment: Have you derived the marginal pmf for $Z$ in part a)? If not, do you have any difficulties in deriving that? If yes, just apply the comment above - divide the joint pmf by the marginal pmf of $Z$.

Comment: @MANMAID How would you find P(B|A) = P(Z=n|U)?

Comment: @sucksatmath $P(Z=z|U=u)=P(U+V=z|U=u)=P(V=z-u)$

Comment: @MANMAID. Then $P(U|Z=n) = p(1-p)^u$? If so,  I don't see how that is is equal to $\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: @sucksatmath can you please write down what is the marginal df of $Z$? more generally write down $P(Z=n)$, please.

Comment: @MANMAID $p(1-p)^{n-u}$?

Comment: It's strange how you get that. You wrote $P(U=u,Z=n)=p^2(1-p)^n$, then $$P(Z=n)=\sum_{u\leq n}p^2(1-p)^n=\sum_{u=0}^{n}p^2(1-p)^n\\=(n+1)p^2(1-p)^n$$

Comment: @MANMAID. Oh I see it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\Pr(U=u) = {} & \Pr(\text{number of failures before the first success} = u) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(\text{failure on the first $u$ trials and success on trial $\#(u+1)$}) \\[10pt]
= {} & p(1-p)^u. \\[20pt]
\Pr(Z=n) = {} & \Pr\Big( (U=0\ \&\ V=n) \text{ or } (U=1\ \&\ V=n-1) \\
& \qquad\qquad \text{or } (U=2\ \& \ V=n-2) \text{ or } (U=3\ \&\ V=n-3) \\
& \qquad\qquad \text{or } (U=4\ \& V=n-4) \text{ or } \cdots\cdots\cdots \Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & p\cdot \big(p(1-p)^n\big) + \big( p(1-p) \big) \cdot \big(p(1-p)^{n-1}\big) + \big(p(1-p)^2\big) \cdot\big(p(1-p)^{n-2}\big) \\[6pt]
&  {} + \big( p(1-p)^3\big)\cdot\big( p(1-p)^{n-3}\big) + \cdots\cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & (n+1)p^2(1-p)^n. \\[10pt] {}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\Pr(U=u \mid Z=n) & = \frac{\Pr(U=u\ \&\ Z=n)}{\Pr(Z=n)} = \frac{\Pr(U=u\ \&\ V=n-u)}{\Pr(Z=n)} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{p(1-p)^u \cdot p(1-p)^{n-u}}{ (n+1)p^2(1-p)^n } = \frac 1 {n+1}.
\end{align}

Thus all $n+1$ possible values of $U$ are equally probable.